# Is there an alternative to TextChangedListener for Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, textchanged

From reading the Android documentation, I understand it is not possible to use addTextChangedListener for Spinner, but is there an alternative that I am missing?

I have created a number of forms and I would like to notify the user when there are unsaved changes (which I can do when I use EditText boxes).

Below is an example of the textChangeListener for EditText:

```
     inspectionReferenceEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         }
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
         }
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             changesMade = true;
         }
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a Spinner does not involve a user typing text, I don't see how a TextWatcher will help. However you can use an [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) to be notified when the user makes a change.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    int previous = -1;
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(previous != position && previous < -1) {
            Log.v("Example", "Item Selected: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            // Do something
        }
        previous = position;
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
});
```

Comment: Ok Sam I'll give it a go and tick ASAP.  Thanks for the quick reply, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sam - issue with this is that if you set the Spinner to show a certain value when the activity is created, the listener reports this as 'onItemSelected'..  I need to be able to set the values in the form, then set the listener..  I guess the work around is to set a counter, then do something when it hits 2..

Comment: I updated the code. As you noticed the listener fires when the Spinner is initialized but it also will fire when the user re-selects the existing choice... I added a quick check against these since you are only interested in substantive changes.